# Disabling Spring @Autowired by-name fallback

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have the following classes defined:

```
public interface Thingy { ... }
public class Foo implements Thingy { ... }
public class Bar implements Thingy { ... }
```

Classes `Foo` and `Bar` are both instanciated as singleton beans with same names, as in

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo" />
<bean id="bar" class="Bar" />
```

The problem happens then trying to autowire field with same name as bean, like

```
@Autowired
Thingy foo;
```

Here, field is autowired with `Foo` instance, and i don't want that. If field name doesn't match bean name, autowiring falis and that's desired.
So, is there any way to disable such fallback, so autowiring in above case would fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, the other way around it is, using `setFallbackToDefaultTypeMatch`:
[javadoc: CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html#setFallbackToDefaultTypeMatch%28boolean%29)

Why don't you just rename either your bean or your class?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions to help you out, although I am not sure exactly what you are asking for is possible.

1. If you are not using the annotation package-scan functionality for discovering beans, then I think in your spring.xml configuration you can specify your beans to have an autowire detection mode.  In the desired bean you specify an element 'autowire', and it has 4 or 5 possible values defined [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire).  I think the one you would want is 'byType'.
2. You could also look into using the [@Qualifier](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation.  This is used for when you have multiple beans of the same type in your application context to help distinguish which bean you actually want to use.
3. Use a different name.  Perhaps this is more simple than you were hoping for, but I think it would help to take care of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Qualifier("beanname") , to ensure you inject it with the correct bean